# Add image to lower bar

Tags: iphone

How to add image to lower bar in tab based application 
I can get the

self.navigationitem

but how to access the lower toolbar anda add background image to it

best regards

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [`UITabBarITem`](http://developerns.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that you can obtain from the `items` property of a UITabBar, or more easily from [the `tabBarItem` property of your `UIViewController`](http://developerns.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarItem).

Then I guess you can set your image using [`image` property](http://developerns.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarItem/image)...

In conclusion :

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBeautifulImage.png"];
```

*might be* what you're looking for (`self` being, ofc, your `UIViewController`)...

**EDIT:** but if your "lower bar in tab based application" is a [`UIToolbar`](http://developerns.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (/me :grins:..) then what you are looking for is a standard [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developerns.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that can be obtained from `UIToolbar.items` property OR some `IBOutlet` property if you wired it using Interface Builder.

In any case, I guess looking at Apple sample codes might be a good idea.

Comment: it's not the tabbaritem , it's a tool bar appear at the bottom of the screen

Comment: the "lower bar in tab based application" is a UITabBar, what do you mean?

Comment: yes I didn't added it , it has been added automatically , how to access it , and set a backgroundimage to it , to access the top one u say self.navigationitem, what about the lower

Comment: there are `self.navigationItem` and `self.tabBarItem` but *there is **no** `self.toolbarItem`* since `UIViewController` is unrelated to `UIToolbar`, you have to add your *own property* to do this.